# Node command line interface change

Tags: node.js, terminal

I'm making a command interface for a node server, but I have reached a point that I want it to look better.

I want to have the console so you enter a command at the bottom of the terminal screen, you hit enter, and it adds the reply to the actual command line.

If you have ever run a minecraft bukkit server from the command line, you should know what I'm talking about.

Here's a picture of what I'm talking about if you still don't understand. Imagine this was in terminal, and ignore the scroll bars: http://cl.ly/1K0h1V0r0H3f3U3t3L22

Is there anyway to set the console to look like this without having to make your own program for it or having the screen reprint all the other info to fake that look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not done this, but I believe something similar is possible with very little effort by using [Node.js REPL](http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html).  You can override the `eval` parameter to provide your own command processing.

It would not have the exact look you are wanting, but it will be an interactive prompt that you can utilize (more similar to a Windows command shell or a Linux shell).

If you want the exact look from your screenshot, I don't believe that there is any Node.js module that will help you.  There are some that allow you to use colors in the console, and some basic highlighting (e.g. bold), but nothing that gives you complete control over the console screen.